# Is it useful to apply mathematical transformations in a NIR spectra before applying LS-SVM?

Tags: svm

I am trying to make predictions for vegetable quality indices with Near Infrared Spectroscopy. I noticed that many machine learning tools are commonly used this purpose. Conventionally, certain transformations like MSC (Multiplicative Scatter Correction), SNV (Standard Normal Variate), and derivatives are used to separate out the more valuable diffuse reflection from the spectra which helps to improve the models. Those methods seemed intuitive for multiple linear regression but I don't understand whether they still hold useful for LS-SVM. In my study they seem to improve the model but I am not sure if it is a good idea to apply preprocessing methods. Besides, I read [here](http://www.yaksis.com/posts/why-use-svm.html) that log and square transformation in the spectra is accounted in the algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is useful to apply these transformation. All these transformation that you mentioned are actually mathematical treatments for noise removal. The SNV removes baseline effect and the first-derivative removes scattering effect. In my experience, first derivative gives better results in most of the cases. You are better off applying these transformations.
Let me know if you are looking for some other specific information.